# Spark map reduce with condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

suppose these are my CSV file:

```
attr1;attr2
11111;MOC
22222;MTC
11111;MOC
22222;MOC
33333;MMS
```

I want to have the number of occurrences in the first column when attr2 = MOC.  Like this :

```
(11111,2)
(22222,1)
```

i've tried:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val textFile = sc.textFile(args(0))

val data = textFile.map(line => line.split(";").map(elem => elem.trim))
val header = new SimpleCSVHeader(data.take(1)(0))

val rows = data.filter(line => header(line,"attr1") != "attr1")
val attr1 = rows.map(row => header(row,"attr1"))
val attr2 = rows.map(row => header(row,"attr2"))
attr1.map( k => (k,1) ).reduceByKey(_+_)

attr1.foreach (println)
```

how can I add the condition in my code?
the result of my code is:

```
(11111,2)
(22222,2)
(33333,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter (again):

```
val rows = data
  .filter(line => header(line,"attr1") != "attr1")
  .filter(line => header(line,"attr2") == "MOC")
```

And then continue as before...

Comment: the console does not display anything